# How to get the current UserId from Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection `users` where every user has his own document. Now I want to create a subcollection to store more data related to a specific user.

This is the code so far:

```
class DatabaseService {

  Future isUserRegistered(String uid) async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
        .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
        .get();
  }

  Future registerNewUser(email, password, uid) async{
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
        .doc(uid).set(
      {
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "uid": uid,
        "token": -1,
        "userGoal": false,
        "userGender": false,
      },
    );
  }
```

I created a save function but instead of storing data in a subcollection within the document with the current uid, firestore creates a new document named 'uid'. How to fix that?

```
  Future saveInSubcollectionToRemote() async{
    Map<String, dynamic> data = UserManager.userWeights;
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
        .doc('uid')
        .collection('weights')
        .doc(data['userWeight'])
        .set(data);
  }

class UserManager {
  static Map<String, dynamic> userWeights = {'weights': []};
}
```

EDIT
This is my google authentication, here i get an id but instead of this id i want the uid

```
  ///Authentication

  void signInGoogle(context) {
    DatabaseService handler = new DatabaseService();
    _googleSignIn
        .signIn()
        .then((userdata) => {
              print(userdata.toString()),
              handler
                  .isUserRegistered(userdata.id.toString())
                  .then((value) => {
                        if (value.docs.length == 0)
                          {
                            print("Not registered"),
                            registerUserToApp(
                                context, userdata.email.toString(), "password", userdata.id.toString())
                          }
                        else
                          {
                            print(value.docs[0].data().toString()),
                            UserManager.userdata = value.docs[0].data(),
                            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) {
                                  return NavBar();
                                },
                              ),
                              (route) => false,
                            ),
                          }
                      })
                  .catchError((e) => {
                        showAlertDialog(
                            context, "Error", ""),
                      })
            })
        .catchError(
            (e) => {showAlertDialog(context, "Error", "")});
  }

  void registerUserToApp(context, email, password, uid) {
    DatabaseService handler = new DatabaseService();
    try {
      handler.registerNewUser(email, password, uid).then((value) => {
            showAlertDialog(context, "Congratulations!",
                "You registered to the app"),
          });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      showAlertDialog(context, "Error", "");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have a UID for the user.  If you did, you would just put it in place of the string 'uid'.  Firestore doesn't manage UIDs for you - you get them from somewhere else, such as Firebase Authentication.

Comment: I use google sign in to sign in. Is this similar to other authentification methods? And how to get the uid? Sorry im new to firestore

Comment: Bottom line is that you're going to have to feed Firestore whatever your identifier is for the user.  Firestore doesn't know it, and can't know it.  It doesn't have "users".  It is just a database, and you have to provide the values to store.  If you are using Firebase Auth, you can assign permissions to users in security rules, but that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `uid` in your code is typically the unique identified of the user. Firestore itself has no knowledge of such a `uid`. Instead, the `uid` comes from the identity provider that you use.

You could use the user ID from Google Sign-in to identify the user in Firestore, but it's more common to sign in with Firebase (too).

Once you've signed in to Google, you can use those credentials to sign in to Firebase Authentication by calling `signInWithCredential` as shown in the documentation on [social authentication](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social#google).

Once you're [signed in to Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage) you'll get a UID from Firebase Authentication, which you can then use to identify the user's documents in Firestore (and later also [secure access to those documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access)).

Once you've done that, you can get the current user (and from there their UID) through `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` (once) or `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` (continuous) and then again use that in your Firestore calls.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the code i have with google sign in to my question. How to implement `signInWithCredential` in my code to get the uid?

Comment: As said, you can use `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` to get the user once the user is signed in, or `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` to listen continuously. From the [`User` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) that you get in both cases, you can get the UID from its `uid` property. I **highly** recommend keeping the documentation I linked handy when coding, as I find it by far the fastest way to answer such questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using `doc('uid')` is setting your document id as `'uid'`. This is whats causing your issue.

Try this:

```
  Future saveInSubcollectionToRemote(String uid) async{
    Map<String, dynamic> data = UserManager.userWeights;
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('weights')
        .doc(data['userWeight'])
        .set(data);
  }
```

pass in `uid` like you did in `registerNewUser()`